# How to assign variable to value fetched from SQL table? (Sqlite 3 and python)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Currently developing a quiz, and need to fetch a random record from the question and answer sections on an sql database table.
My question is how do you assign the values you have fetched into a variable, such that I would be able to place it in a widget in Tkinter and use the answer variable to compare with the answer inputted by the user?

```
quizQuestion = cursor.execute("SELECT Question, Answer FROM questionandanswer WHERE Difficulty = 1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;")
```

So I have obtained a question and answer, but need to assign them both into two separate variables, quizQuestion and quizAnswer.

Thanks alot

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: have u tried saying `data = cursor.fetchall()` and try `print(data)` and see if it has all the things u want

Comment: Cool Cloud, have tried but nothing works. AMC, I believe the code I have provided fits the critieria. I have showed the fetching of a question and answer, and im now asking whether you can assign the question and the answer into a variable

Comment: which language is dis? MySQL? sqlite?

Comment: sqlite3 and python

Comment: u said u have tried and nothing works , what do yo u mean nothign works, is there an error or an empty list printing out ?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar, I used a web API to get trivia questions and stored them into an `sqlite3` database.

To get a specific question you can simply use this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE QUESTION LIKE ?;", (str(question),)).fetchall()
```

this returns a list of all the results of the query, each result will be represented as a tuple and will have the fields you requested, ordered by the indexes you provided.

If you wish to get a random question your syntax should work if you add a `fetchall()` function call.

If it still does not work you can try to do it in a less efficient way and simply fetch all the questions from the database and choose one randomly in python, if your database is not massive it shouldn't really matter.

Now you can simply access the results in the list:

```py
# fetch multiple columns:
data = con.execute("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS;").fetchall()
for entry_tuple in data:
    quizQuestion = entry_tuple[0]
    quizAnswer = entry_tuple[1]
    # Do whatever you want to do with the data

# Or fetch specific column:
data = con.execute("SELECT Question, Answer FROM questionandanswer WHERE Difficulty = 1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;").fetchall()
question_tuple = data[0]
quizQuestion = question_tuple [0]
quizAnswer = question_tuple [1]
```